# Ternary operator creating temporaries for returned references in C++

Tags: c++, reference, ternary

Why is the ternary operator creating a temporary variable for **a&** to reference in the case of:

```
SeqNo &fb(int x);
SeqNo &fc(int x);

SeqNo &a = cond ? fb(y):fc(y);
```

Note that the code updates **a** later i.e.

```
a= value;
```

fails to update the original variable referenced by the return value from fc() or fb() and therefore **a** must point to a temporary whilst changing the code to

```
if( cond) {
  SeqNo & a = fb(y);
  a=value;
} else {
  SeqNo &a = fc(y);
  a=value;
}
```

updates the original variable referenced by fb() and fc() correctly.

Note fc() and fb() both return variables of the same type (&SeqNo) and the variable referenced by the functions is of identical and same type i.e SeqNo. So no conversion should be taking place on the returned references.

I have checked for duplicates on stack overflow but the answers are for when the arguments of ? returns different types convertible to a single type or when slicing occurs. In this case the arguments are for the same type and no conversions should have occurred for any of them.

Comment: I [failed to reproduce](https://godbolt.org/g/vnyiJq). Can you try to create a [mcve]? Thanks :)

Comment: This is impossible, something wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: SORRY, you are correct. Turned out to be to be a combination of gdb giving bad results for optimised and template code making it very difficult to step through and determine that another thread was resetting the sequence numbers back to the starting values making it look as if the numbers where not being updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeqNo &fb(int x);
SeqNo &fc(int x);

SeqNo &a = cond ? fb(y):fc(y);
```

If the object returned by fb and fc is created inside them, it has no sense to return by reference, because that object doesn't exist out of the scope of fb and fc, so you get an invalid reference and the risk of unexpected behaviour.

```
SeqNo &fb(int x)
{
  SeqNo res;
  ...
  return res;
}
```

as I said, res doesn't exist after the execution of fb.

If instead the object returned by fb and fc, was existing already before, for example as static variable, then you will be able to work always on the same instance

```
static SeqNo obj;

SeqNo &fb(int x)
{
  //work on obj
  ...
  return obj;
}
```